# How to get hours and minutes from interval of seconds in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I have a time difference between two datetimes. The interval in seconds is 3660 which means 1 hour and 1 minute ago. How can i show the interval of seconds in hours and minutes like i said before? i can get the hours by doing `(3600/60)/60` which gives me the one hour but how do i get the remaining minutes along with the hour?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int totalTime = 3660;
int hours = totalTime / 3600;
int minutes = (totalTime % 3600) / 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the *modulo* operator:

```
(3660 / 60) % 60 = 1
```

Example of modulo:

```
0 % 3 = 0
1 % 3 = 1
2 % 3 = 2
3 % 3 = 0
4 % 3 = 1
5 % 3 = 2
6 % 3 = 0
7 % 3 = 1
...
```

See the pattern here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the C `div` function for getting the quotient and remainder with a single function call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  //div_t

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int seconds = 3661;
  div_t hrmin, minsec;
  minsec = div(seconds, 60);
  hrmin = div(minsec.quot, 60);

  printf("%i seconds equals %i hours, %i minutes and %i seconds.\n", \
         seconds, hrmin.quot, hrmin.rem, minsec.rem);

  return 0;
}
```